Cannot make multiple requests sequentially with await in a for const of loop
I'm trying to upload chunks of a file to Google Drive with Drive API. I implement it in a for const of loop with await to execute requests (fetch API).
It ensures that the file is correctly uploaded.
In web javascript, everything works perfectly. However in React Native only the first the request is successful:

The second request fails causing the framework to throw Network request failed and all the rest of requests fail (don't know why the first request is successful).
I even add a await sleep of 5s but same error still fires.
react-native ver: 0.64.2
device: iPhone 15 Pro Max simulator on Macbook 14 inch 2021
Update:
It seems to work perfectly on real device. There must be some limitations on the iOS simulator.

Share your code. How do you send the request? What is the detailed error message?

it's a simple await upload(args[i]) but it seems to work perfectly on real device. There must be some limitations on the iOS simulator.
